# check char from array if it exist in a string got wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input html element and I am using a blur funtion in jquery to check if the value contains an specific element but my code is not working.

```
jQuery( "#email" ).blur(function() {
...
var arr = ["1","6","7"];
if(this.value()){ // check if the string value contains characters in arr Array
..
```

any idea?
I tried also to use `indexOf()` but still not working

}
...

...

Comment: How did you use `indexOf`, `this.value()` is wrong, it should be just `this.value`

Comment: Since you want to check char by char, you might have to use `keypress` event

Comment: i can't use keypress some android devices can't recognize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
jQuery("#email").blur(function() {
  var arr = ["1","6","7"];
  // Check if string contains characters above
  var charactersInString = arr.some(function(chr) {
    return this.value.indexOf(chr) >= 0;
  });

  // charactersInString will be true if any of the 
  //characters in the array are in the input string
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this snippet will be useful

```
// Defining array of predefined chars outside the blur event.
// No need to define it on every blur event.
var arr = ["1","6","7"]; //array of predefined chars.
$( "#email" ).blur(function(event) { // Expecting an input element
var _getText = $(this).val();  // get the value from input
for(var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){  // loop through array of predefined chars
  // use indexOf to check if input val 
  //contain any of predefined chars
  if(_getText.indexOf(arr[i]) ==-1){  
   console.log(arr[i] + " is not present in the string");
  }
  else{
   console.log(arr[i]+ " is present in the string");
  }
}
})
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/q19xad1m/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I have a different approach, I hope will be of great help:

```
(function($) {
    var arr = ["1","6","7"];

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var email = document.getElementById("email");
        var lastCharacter;

        email.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
            lastCharacter = this.value.substr(-1);

            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] === lastCharacter) {
                    console.log("Exist - Contains an specific element of the Arr");
                }
            }

        }, false);

    });

})(jQuery);
```